# How do i estimate download time when response header does not contain content-length?

Tags: python, urllib2, content-length

how do i estimate download progress/time when the file to be downloaded lacks the content-length information? Thanks

Comment: To get progress, you need the current size and the total size. If you don't know the total size, it's impossible to know how big the file is unless you download it fully, which would render a progress useless.

Comment: `import random; `print 10**10**10**10 * random.uniform()` Repeat at regular intervals to provide the user with updated estimates.

Comment: You could guess... Most of the time that's what those estimates look like anyway...

Comment: use MS© progress© bar©:
start downloading, show 0%
when finished, jump to 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You you find yourself in the rather improbable situation that the server won't send you content lengths but accepts byte range requests (and you really really need to know how long it'll take), you can use the code in [Python seek on remote file using HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1971240/555569) and do a binary search to get some notion about the file size. Ask for a range beyond the file size and you'll receive:

```
HTTPError: HTTP Error 416: Requested Range Not Satisfiable
```