# Fetch only the last 128 bytes of an mp3 file over a http connection

Tags: python, http, tags, mp3

I have been looking for an example of how python could fetch only the last 128 bytes of an mp3 file over a http connection. Is it possible to do range specific file access over HTTP in python?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it is possible to do it via HTTP using urllib2.

```
class HTTPRangeHandler(urllib2.BaseHandler):

    def http_error_206(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
        # Range header supported
        r = urllib.addinfourl(fp, hdrs, req.get_full_url())
        r.code = code
        r.msg = msg
        return r

    def http_error_416(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
        # Range header not supported
        raise URLError('Requested Range Not Satisfiable')

opener = urllib2.build_opener(HTTPRangeHandler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

rangeheader = {'Range':'bytes=-128'}
req = urllib2.Request('http://path/to/your/file.mp3',headers=rangeheader)
res = urllib2.urlopen(req)
res.read()
```

The following SO question ([Python Seek on remote file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971240/python-seek-on-remote-file/1971294#1971294)) had this asked/answered.
While using the same solution, all you need is set the bytes to -128. (The HTTP manual describes that when you do -value, it is the value quantity at the end of the response)

Comment: You should include, that the code should check if the returned HTTP-Status is 206 (Partial Content) instead of 200 (OK). This way it should be possible to detect wether the server supported the Rang-Header.

Comment: @Martin. Yes, it should be. Updated.

Answer (score 5):

You could try to only request the last 128 bytes using the [*Range* header field](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35):

```
Range: bytes=-128
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the [httpheader](http://deron.meranda.us/python/httpheader/) module (see the "Using http range requests" example).